# agm/core localization Angular

Tags: angular, agm-core

I want to localize google maps component using "@agm/core": "1.0.0" and switching languages without reloading browser.
Any ideas?

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: 'apikey',
  language: localStorage && localStorage.gml || 'en'
}),
```

The above code is working only if you reload the browser tab.